# Fish shell - remove file and execute command

Tags: shell, fish

I want to execute the simple command

```
rm -f *.zip or true ; and date
```

Meaning I want to delete all zip files in the current path and show the current date. I want to see the date anyway. Even if there are no such files.

I would do it in bash as:

```
rm -f *.zip || true; date
```

This is what I  get in fish:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Reading documentation I found that

[image]

So it turns out that (I can't believe it)

I should write simple `rm -f *.zip` as

```
set files *.zip
   if count $files > /dev/null
     rm -f *.zip
end
```

I am pretty unhappy with such solution,

there must be something better

**UPDATE**
 I tried

```
rm -f "*.zip"; date
```

But it doesn't remove files because no expansion happens

**Update**

I though of hiding expression in function as

```
                    function rmf
                    set files $argv
                    set quantity (count $files)
                        if [ $quantity -gt 0 ]
                            echo "yes";
                            rm -f $files
                        else
                          echo "not enough"
                    end  
                end
```

But the problem is that rmf function is not treated as count function

Comment: Why don't you just do `rm *.zip; date`?

Comment: in bash it will ask for confirmation, I don't want to have one. This is a simplified example (actually I have a bigger script)  i.e. this is a habit. This is non-issue http://kagda.ru/i/11015641163_24-08-2017-21:35:50_1101.png

Comment: @ГляОпаОпа, ГляОпаОпа - sounds pretty funny (dealing with our Ukrainian mentality) :-)

Comment: Please don't use the bash tag if someone with bash expertise can't answer the question.

Comment: Eh? "In bash it will ask for confirmation"? Only if you have, maybe, an alias or function adding the `-i` argument to `rm`; out of the box, with no customization from your OS or distro, bash does no such thing.

Comment: yes, it's aliased by default in ubuntu distro. unaliasing it is not a sane thing. This is not issue anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a frustrating case, I agree. fish's wildcard expansion behavior is almost always better (try `touch *.zip` in bash to see why) with the very important and annoying exception of `rm`.

Probably the simplest workaround is:

```
set tmp *.zip ; rm -f $tmp ; date
```

Comment: it works because  "set" is exception for expanding (also "count") . There is also a third special function , I can't remember how it's named, can you?

Comment: `for` (as in `for file in *`), `set` and `count` are the exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

```
set files *.zip
set -q files[1]
and rm -f $files
date
```

Comment: takes too long to type. Manual claims that "2. Fish should be user friendly," so there must be  more frienlier way like  rm -f * in bash

Answer (score 0):

Final command:

```
rm -f *.zip ; date
```

It works fine BUT  in fish 2.6, when I had the problem I used fish 2.2. 
They changed behaviour in later versions.

Plus some caveats:

No need for **and** before date, 
it behaves like  && in  bash so it ignores

Yes it produces error but it does what it should

See this issue https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/683

Exact explanation why:

[image]

Comment: I'm using fish, version 3.6.1 and I have the issue

Comment: @Dorian  Just run this command in bash, from experience .  `bash -c "rm -f *.zip; date"` without leaving lovely fish shell

Comment: I did `set gems *.gem; rm $gems`